# Can't get a python file to run 2 other python files on parallel

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, python-multiprocessing, file-handling

So I have been trying for hours..DAYS to figure out a code to run 2 python files simultaneously.

I have tried subprocesses, multiprocessing, bash and whatnot, I must be doing something wrong, I just don't know what.

I have 2 python files, and I want to run them in parallel, but note that neither of them end. I want, while the first file is open and running, to run a second file.

Everything I have tried only opens the first file and stops there, since the script there is supposed to be running 24/7. Note that when I tried to use a separate bash file, it, for some reason, opened on git and then closed, doing nothing. I'm really desperate at this point ngl

Please do provide detailed answers with code, as I have been scanning the whole internet (StackOverflow included), I have tried everything and nothing seems to be working..

```py
import subprocess
import LemonBot_General
import LemonBot_Time
import multiprocessing

def worker(file):
  subprocess.Popen(["python3 LemonBot_Time.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  subprocess.Popen(["python3 LemonBot_General.py"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    files = ["LemonBot_General.py","LemonBot_Time.py"]
    for i in files:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i,))
        p.start()
```

This is the latest I tried and didn't work..
I also tried the subprocess commands alone, that didn't work as well.
Bash file also didn't work.

EDIT: NEITHER of the files FINISH. I want to run them in parallel.

Comment: "Please do provide detailed answers with code, as I have been scanning the whole internet (StackOverflow included), I have tried everything and nothing seems to be working.." You need to show us what you've tried and describe how you expect it to work and how it isn't working.

Comment: It's really a lot of things, I believe I did something wrong that was supposed to work. I expect to have 2 scripts that dont end running at the same time.

I can't show exactly, since I have deleted everything that wasnt working...sorry

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Managed to find something, updated.

Comment: why are you importing the code into one process and also invoking separate python process to execute each file?

Comment: @SamMason What do you mean? I import the scripts in order to not write the whole directory every time and use Popen to open them, but it only opens 1 file, because they don't finish. The last part of the code was a possible solution I found in StackOverflow, which didn't work.

Comment: I think you've posted this question because you're misunderstanding how modules/importing work in Python.  try putting `print` statements after each `import` statement, as I guess you're not running code in the `Popen` just as a side effect of importing the module

Comment: Yes I realized that later. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use Popen from subproccess. Worked for me. If you remove the `p.wait()` line, the second file will quit as soon as this first file finishes.

```py
import time
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'test_file.py'])

time.sleep(5)
print("Working well")

p.wait()
```

Comment: Edit: I got it to work using your script, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use the os.system('python3 myprogram.py') command inside of a threading.thread() command for each file.

Comment: Still opens only 1 of the 2 files :/